# Given text file with names, if folder has files with such names - delete it, else make folder with this name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I was curious to make a script in windows cmd that is taking source.txt file with such names:

```
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
User6
```

Secondly, I have created the destination folder F:\Destination
The task is to iterate with source.txt and if a file from this txt exists at the address F:\Destination, delete it, if such file does not exist, create a folder with this name.

For example:
I have User1.txt User2.txt and User3.txt in F:\Destination
and I need to delete them and create folders User4 User5 and User6

Here is my script, but sadly it's doing nothing

```
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %G in ("source.txt") do if exist
"Destination\%~G" del "Destination\%~G" if not exist "Destination\%~G" md "Destination\%~G"
```

Hope to get some advice, thanks!

Comment: You're code is not a valid shell syntax, that is windows thing.

Comment: @Jetchisel Sorry I forgot to mention, that it is just windows cmd script :)

Comment: Your error is clearly explained within thr first few lines of the help information for the `for` command. Change `%G` and `%~G` to `%%G` and `%%~G` respectively. Next time, please read the syntax and usage information for all of your commands, by oprning a Comnand Prompt window, typong `command /?` and pressing the `[ENTER]` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For /F "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("source.txt") do (
 if exist "Destination\%%~G.txt" del "Destination\%%~G.txt" 
 ) else (md "Destination\%%~G")
```

This assumes that your code forms part of a batch file.

Since `source.txt` contains the names without the extension `.txt`, you need to add the extension in.

Note that if the file does not exist, but the directory already exists, you'll get an error (directory already exists) which you can suppress by appending  `2>nul` to the `md` command (within the parentheses)

You should also note that running the job a second time will create the directory since the first run will have deleted the file.